# How to add a custom data-bind function to a minicart item in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, requirejs

I'm trying to add some functionality to the minicart product items. On product list and view I was able to add this throught requirejs/knockout. Now, I can't find how to work with the minicart item. How can I add functions to the uiComponent for a minicart product item?

Answer (score 0):

No problem here, just override this files in your theme or module:

For editing minicart template:
***vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html***

For editing item renderer template:
***vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html***

For adding functionality:
***vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js***